# Change server for Immediate Alerts job

Tags: 2013, timer-jobs

While investigating why alert emails weren't going out, I discovered that the Immediate Alerts jobs were associated with a WFE server.  On that server, the SharePoint Timer Service had been disabled (intentionally, we only have it enabled on the app servers).

I enabled and started the service, and all pending alerts went out.

How can I change the jobs so that they don't try to use a service that's disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer service is for all administrative, deployment, and services from a very high level, including updating configuration and those servers to the farm. Turning the timer service off can be problematic.

If you want emails to go out on a specific server, enable the SMTP service and follow [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to set up SMTP and the configuration that goes along with it. You can probably disable the SMTP server that the WFE service is in.

Comment: Thanks, so you'd recommend enabling the timer service on all servers in the farm, including WFEs?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't permanently stop the timer service for any reason, but sometimes the timer service needs to be restarted.